# Tap detection not working on UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my .m file I added:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *star1;
```

Then in a method I did:

```
UIImage *star1Image;
star1Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"staryes"];
self.star1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
self.star1.tag = 800;
[self.star1 setImage:star1Image];
[ratingLabelBody addSubview:self.star1];
```

After a few lines not related to this I have:

```
[self.star1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgTouchUp:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.star1 addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

And finally in the .m file I have implemented:

```
-(void)imgTouchUp:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"imgTouchUp");
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    NSLog(@"tap detected on %li", (long)gesture.view.tag);
}
```

With all this, it should recognize the tap on my image but nothing is happening. Any idea?

Comment: `ratingLabelBody` a `UILabel`? Did you do: `[ratingLabelBody setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` too?

Comment: @Larme You are right, I forgot to add the `setUserInteractionEnabled` to `YES`. (Btw, `ratingLabelBody` is an `UIView`). It's working now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, since components like `UILabel` or `UIImageView` aren't design to be "touchable", to add a "touchable" feature (like a `UITapRecognizer`), you have to set their `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`.

So, even if you set this property correctly for your `UIImageView` (`star1`), since you add it as a subview of `ratingLabelBody`, you couldn't trigger your `UITapGestureRecognizer` (`imgTouchUp:`).
You have to do the same to the parent view of your `star1`, which is `ratingLabelBody`.

Translated with code, you just had to do:

```
[ratingLabelBody setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```