# UITextField and tap gesture in leftView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've an icon on leftView of textField and I want to add tap gesture to it. This is my code :

```
if (!textField.leftView){
    UIImageView *infoImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 18)];
    infoImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info"];
    infoImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    textField.leftView = infoImage;
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showErrorMessage:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [infoImage addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

The problem when user click on the image on leftview nothing is happend and the `showErrorMessage` is not called .

**Update**
The tap issue was solved by enabling userInteraction on the infoImage. 
But now I'm getting `[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` at second line of my  Show `errorMessage` :

```
-(void)showErrorMessage:(id)sender{
UIImageView *icon = (UIImageView *)sender;
NSString *key = [@(icon.tag) stringValue];
NSLog(@"%@", [_errorDictionary objectForKey:key]);
```

}

Comment: `infoImage. userInteractionEnabled = YES`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tap detection not working on UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765590/tap-detection-not-working-on-uiimageview)

Comment: The sender is not the `imageView`, it's the `tapGestureRecognizer`...

Comment: @Misha I'm setting tag in this way `infoImage.tag = textField.tag;`

Comment: The problem is what Emilio mentioned

Comment: @EmilioPelaez how to change the sender to UIImageView instead of tapGesture because I can't use `tapGestureRecognizer.tag`

Comment: You need to do the following: ((UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender).view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing `infoImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the image's property userInteractionEnabled to TRUE