# Trouble with tap gestures

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tap gesture on a `UIImageView` within a class that extends `UITableViewCell`. This code should work, I don't see why it doesn't. The only thing I am iffy on is what the "target" should be - should it be the `profileImage`, or the overall ViewController that things are in?

```
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!    

var vc: TweetsViewController? = nil

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tapGester = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: vc, action: Selector("handleTapGester:"))
    tapGester.delegate = self
    profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGester)
}

func handleTapGester(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("*******hi*******")
    vc?.performSegueWithIdentifier("showProfile", sender: nil)
}
```

And for the record, as this may seem like a relevant error, I initialize vc when the table cell loads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tap detection not working on UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765590/tap-detection-not-working-on-uiimageview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target should be the object that will handle the tap gesture and the handleTapGester function should be inside the object class you specified as the target, not inside the UITableViewCell subclass.

You also need to enable user interaction on the UIImageView by saying:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a tap gesture recogniser to the view, then when called query indexPathForRowAtPoint to find out which cell is being tapped?

If you know the cell you can then determine if the UIImage is being tapped and make your call to performSegueWithIdentifier from there.

If it's tapped on a cell that you're not interested in let it fall through and be handled by the table by calling cancelsTouchesInView on the recogniser.